# mount crypto_LUKS partition without decrypting (locally)

Tags: encryption, luks, disk-encryption

I have an encrypted external disk on a linux server.

On the server, I can do this locally to decrypt
`cryptsetup -d keyfile luksOpen /dev/sdx1 /mnt/decrypted`
but I prefer to avoid doing that on the server side.

I want to access the server (via ssh/sshfs) and only decrypt the data remotely on my client machine.

To access and decrypt the data remotely, I have to

1. mount the encrypted `/dev/sdx1` locally on the server (without decrypting it!!) to `/mnt/encrypted`
2. mount `/mnt/encrypted` via sshfs on a client machine (then use `luksOpen` to decrypt)

How can I do step 1 without decrypting data?

Thanks,
Chris

ps: maybe I should just use an encrypted container (a file on the server's file system) and not a whole partition? 
This way I could mount the folder containing the encrypted container/file remotely via sshfs? (and only decrypt it on the client machine)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4976/can-i-share-a-device-from-under-dev-across-hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can mount and decrypt luks remotely (via `sshfs`) if I use a luks container (and not a luks partition) to hold the encrypted data.

I just had to create a luks container (a file that holds internally the encrypted filesystem), this file is a normal file on a mounted partition so it can be mounted remotely via `sshfs` and decrypted later (via loop device -> mapper device -> mount).

I have tested this and I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to achieve with your current setup.

The only "proper" way to do that is to put your luks volume on a [Network Block Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device).

You may use `drbd` or `iscsi` to access the block device on your server and then setup Luks on it.

Comment: thanks for the answer! what about using an encrypted luks container/file (not a partition), would that work across sshfs?

Comment: something like

/srv/encrypted.img  <---sshfs---->   /client/encrypted.img -> /dev/loop0 -> cryptsetup luksOpen -> mount /dev/mapper/dm0 /mnt/decrypted

Comment: Yeah, that will probably work. You can also use [`cryptmount`](http://cryptmount.sourceforge.net/) which way of operation looks more compatible to what you want to do. Anyway, with that solution, take care of your private key which is usually stored under /etc/ ... if it's lost, your data are too.

Comment: I can confirm now: yes I can mount and decrypt luks remotely (via sshfs) if I use a luks container (not a luks partition) to hold the encrypted data. 

I just had to create a luks container (a file that holds internally the encrypted filesystem), this file is a normal file on a mounted partition so it can be mounted remotely via sshsfs and decrypted later (via loop device -> mapper device -> mount). Thanks